# Is there a way to get current site url

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites, url

In my community site, I wanna get current site url in my apex class.
I want to get the whole url, not just the domain part
Instead of https://abc.site.com/
I want the whole https://abc.site.com/page?key1=xxx&key2=xxx
All I can find is the way to get domain part, don't know how to do this.
Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

From the question, it seems like you want to get the complete URL(+Query Parameter) and do some processing in Apex.

> You can not get the query parameters directly in apex as apex does not
>   have any context.

Assuming you are calling Apex method from VF page or Lightning component from inside community, you can get the complete URL in JS using `window.location.href` and then pass it to apex